# Passing a variable to a button's handler

Tags: extjs, extjs5

In my interface i have created this button :

```
{
        xtype: 'button',
        width: 196,
        height: 29,
        hidden: false,
        text: Strings.sharedNotifications,
        glyph: 'xf003@FontAwesome',
        handler: 'onNotificationsClick',
        reference: 'settingsNotificationsButton',
        cls: 'buttonsCls',
         id : 'settingsMenuButton7'
    }
```

And in the controller i define this function as the handler for the above button :

```
 onNotificationsClick: function () {
                Ext.create('Mine.view.BaseWindow', {
                    title: Strings.sharedNotifications,
                    items: {
                        xtype: 'notificationsView'
                    }
                }).show();
            },
```

I want to apply an additional style (add a CSS class with `addCls` method) on the panel it gets displayed on click depending on some global variable defined in the controller. How to pass the variable (say `var dark;`) to the `onNotificationsClick` in order to style the panel on click.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would fire an event in the handler.  When you fire the event you can pass arguments.

[Here is a fiddle.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3aa8)

Comment: What if i had to listen to that event in a different controller ? does the event goes global in the app ?

Comment: Also my handler is in the controller (not defined alongside the button object) how to pass the `button` argument in this case ?

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show how to pass the button as an argument to the event.  As for the listener, I think controllers can only listen to events that are children of their view.  In the "control" config of the controller you use selectors to define what components and events you want this controller to listen for.   I made a change in the fiddle to show this.

Comment: Here is something to look at https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/guides/application_architecture/view_controllers.html#application_architecture-_-view_controllers_-_listeners_and_event_domains  THis talks about how the vents bubble up to controllers ... so a controller can only see events for its descendants